# HTML form rows disappear when changing one particular form field

Tags: python, html, ajax, forms, flask

I am working on a feature that allow to update the properties of a node (name etc.). So in my changeservice.html I first populate a list with all nodes. Then depending on the selection an AJAX function is fetching all node details and pre-populates a form. Now everything works fine, I can change the values of all fields but one input in particular - service_name . Then for some reason all other fields disappear from the screen and are not even submitted with the POST afterwards, resulting in the following error:

> > File "C:\Users\nb67ab\Envs\virtualobeya4dec\virtualobeya\views.py", line 437, in changeservice features_1 = request.form['features_1']
> >     File
> >     "C:\Users\nb67ab\Envs\virtualobeya4dec\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py",
> >     line 443, in **getitem** raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
> >     werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser
> >     (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
> >     KeyError: 'features_1'

My HTML looks like:

```html
{% extends "layouts/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="main-content">
    <!-- Basic Form area Start -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Form row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Change Service</h4>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="service_selected" class="col-form-label">Select Service or PB</label>
                                <select id="service_selected" name="platform_selected" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Choose</option>
                                    {% for x in services %}
                                        <option value="{{x.name}},{{ x.type }},{{ x.pname }}">{{ x.name }},{{ x.type }},{{ x.pname }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card"  id="service_details" style="display: none">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ url_for('changeservice') }}" method="post">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div id="service_name_old" class="form-group col-md-4" style="display: none">
                                    <label for="servicenameold" class="col-form-label">Service Name Old</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="servicenameold" id="servicenameold" placeholder="">
                                    <label for="domainnameold" class="col-form-label">Domain Name Old</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domainnameold" id="domainnameold" placeholder="">
                                    <label for="platformnameold" class="col-form-label">Platform Name Old</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="platformnameold" id="platformnameold" placeholder="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="EPS" name="type" class="custom-control-input" value="EPS" checked>
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="EPS">Exposed Platform Service</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="ESPB" name="type" class="custom-control-input" value="ESPB">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="ESPB">Exposed Supplied Product Build</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="ETES" name="type" class="custom-control-input" value="ETES">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="ETES">Exposed Tied Engineering Support</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="ET" name="type" class="custom-control-input" value="ET">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="ET">Exposed Training&Counseling</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="selected_domain" class="col-form-label">Select domain where service belongs</label>
                                    <select id="selected_domain" name="selected_domain" class="form-control">
                                        <option>Choose</option>
                                        {%for x in domain%}
                                            <option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
                                        {%endfor%}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="selected_platform" class="col-form-label">Select platform exposing the service</label>
                                    <select name="selected_platform" id="selected_platform" class="form-control">
                                        <option>Choose</option>
                                        {%for x in platform%}
                                            <option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
                                        {%endfor%}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="col-form-label">Service Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="service_name" id="service_name" placeholder="Service Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div id="features" class="form-group col-md-3">
                                </div>
                                <div  id="options" class="form-group col-md-3">
                                </div>
                                <div id="qualities" class="form-group col-md-3">
                                </div>
                                <div id="aspects" class="form-group col-md-3">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Service</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="message-box">
                                {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
                                    <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/ajax.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

The Ajax Script looks like:

```js
$("#service_selected").on('change', function(){
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/returnservicedetails',
            data:{
                serviceselect: $("#service_selected").val()
                },

            success: function (data,status,xhr) {   // success callback function
                if (data.length > 0){
                    var js = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(data);
                    var servicename = js[0]['name'];
                    var type = js[0]['type'];
                    var domain=js[0]['dname'];
                    var platform=js[0]['pname'];
                    var features=js[0]['features'];
                    var serviceoptions = js[0]['options'];
                    var qualities=js[0]['qualities'];
                    var aspects = js[0]['aspects'];
                    $('#servicenameold').val(servicename);
                    $('#service_name').val(servicename);
                    if (type=='EPS') {
                        $('#EPS').prop('checked',true);
                        $(':radio:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (type=='ESPB') {
                            $('#ESPB').prop('checked',true);
                            $(':radio:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
                        }
                        else {
                            if (type=='ETES') {
                                $('#ETES').prop('checked',true)
                                $(':radio:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#ET').prop('checked',true)
                                $(':radio:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $('#selected_domain').val(domain);
                    $('#domainnameold').val(domain);
                    $('#selected_platform').val(platform);
                    $('#platformnameold').val(platform)
                    var features1 = '<label class="col-form-label">Features</label>';
                    for (var j = 0; j < features.length; j++) {
                        features1 += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="features_' + (j + 1) + '" id="features_' + (j + 1) + '" placeholder="" value="' + features[j]+'" >';
                    }
                    $("#features").empty('').append(features1);
                    var serviceoptions1 = '<label class="col-form-label">Options</label>';
                    for (var j = 0; j < serviceoptions.length; j++) {
                        serviceoptions1 += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="options_' + (j + 1) + '" id="options_' + (j + 1) + '" placeholder="" value="' + serviceoptions[j]+'" >';
                    }
                    $("#options").empty('').append(serviceoptions1);
                    var qualities1 = '<label class="col-form-label">Qualities</label>';
                    for (var j = 0; j < qualities.length; j++) {
                        qualities1 += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="qualities_' + (j + 1) + '" id="qualities_' + (j + 1) + '" placeholder="" value="' + qualities[j]+'" >';
                    }
                    $("#qualities").empty('').append(qualities1);
                    var aspects1 = '<label class="col-form-label">Aspects</label>';
                    for (var j = 0; j < aspects.length; j++) {
                        aspects1 += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="aspects_' + (j + 1) + '" id="aspects_' + (j + 1) + '" placeholder="" value="' + aspects[j]+'" >';
                    }
                    $("#aspects").empty('').append(aspects1);
                    $("#service_details").show()
                    }
                else {
                    $("#service_details").hide()
                    }

                },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { // error callback
            }
        });
    })
```

The Python endpoint looks like:

```
@app.route('/changeservice', methods=["GET","POST"])
def changeservice():
    user=User(session["username"])
    if request.method=="POST":
        servicenameold=request.form['servicenameold']
        domainnameold=request.form['domainnameold']
        platformnameold=request.form['platformnameold']
        newservicename=request.form['service_name']
        domainnamenew=request.form['selected_domain']
        platformnamenew=request.form['selected_platform']
        stype=request.form['type']
        features_1 = request.form['features_1']
        features_2 = request.form['features_2']
        features_3 = request.form['features_3']
        features_4 = request.form['features_4']
        options_1 = request.form['options_1']
        options_2 = request.form['options_2']
        options_3 = request.form['options_3']
        options_4 = request.form['options_4']
        qualities_1 = request.form['qualities_1']
        qualities_2 = request.form['qualities_2']
        qualities_3 = request.form['qualities_3']
        qualities_4 = request.form['qualities_4']
        aspects_1 = request.form['aspects_1']
        aspects_2 = request.form['aspects_2']
        aspects_3 = request.form['aspects_3']
        aspects_4 = request.form['aspects_4']
        features_all = [features_1, features_2, features_3, features_4]
        options_all = [options_1, options_2, options_3, options_4]
        qualities_all = [qualities_1, qualities_2, qualities_3, qualities_4]
        aspects_all = [aspects_1, aspects_2, aspects_3, aspects_4]
        if not newservicename or not domainnamenew or not platformnamenew:
            flash("You must specify Service Name, Domain and Platform")
        else:
            nodeid=Services.returnexposedID(servicenameold,stype,platformnameold)
            servicedetails=Services.returnExposedDetails(nodeid)
            if servicedetails[0]['name']==newservicename and servicedetails[0]['features']==features_all and servicedetails[0]['options']==options_all and servicedetails[0]['qualities']==qualities_all and servicedetails[0]['aspects']==aspects_all and servicedetails[0]['dname']==domainnamenew and servicedetails[0]['pname']==platformnamenew:
                flash("No changes were made")
            else:
                user.unhookServiceFromPandD(nodeid)
                user.updateExposedProperties(nodeid,newservicename,domainnamenew,platformnamenew,features_all,options_all,qualities_all,aspects_all)
                user.updateExposedsurroundings(nodeid)
    platforms = Platforms.listAllplatforms()
    domains = Domains.listdomains()
    services=Services.listallexposed()
    return render_template("changeservice.html",services=services,platform=platforms,domain=domains)
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that all variables in Javascript are global, I had another function listening on a field with the same name.